# How to display build status of projects

Tags: azure-devops

We have several projects maintained in our VSTS repositories, and these are configured to auto-build on a commit/pull-request complete.

Many years ago, a company I worked for had a wall-mounted monitor which showed a grid of red/green 'tiles', each with the project name in it. These got updated automatically as a commit was made into SVN and a build started. I can't recall the name of the app we used.

Is there something similar for VSTS? I've searched for dashboards, etc., but that doesn't return anything like I've described.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want in each project know his status you can add to his dashboard the "Build History" widget, then you will see the build history of the project with nice green/red indicates.

Add the widget:

[image]

Configure:

[image]

Results:

[image]

You can also install the [Team Project Health](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TeamProjectHealth) widget, it enables users to visualize the overall health of builds, delivering a visual cue similar to the Codify Build Light:

[image]

Or you can install the [Project Tile](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=heymrcarter.ProjectTile) widget:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That sort of sounds like CruiseControl.NET or something similar.  But, VSTS (now Azure Devops, or AD for short) does have a dashboard but you have to put each and every build definition status by hand.  I don't like it.  But, you could create your own dashboard with some simple html and just refresh it very x-number of seconds.  Just copy and past the build badge from the build definition shown in the image below.  And if the build fails, then a RED badge will be shown with the text "failure" or something like that.
[image]

Comment: CruiseControl - that was the app we used. I'd forgotten its name - thanks for reminding me ;-)  Where does the image you pasted above come from? Is it the Azure DevOps Dashboard you mentioned?

Comment: The image above is inside a Build Definition https://imgur.com/awod0Ug (now called a Build Pipeline).  This is not the Azure Devops Dashboard.  The dashboard is visible in the same image in this comment.  You can have more than one dashboard.

Comment: If you just copy the sample URL that I squared in RED in the answer above, you can create you own dashboard that will show the GREEN or RED badge to show the build status for a dashboard for everyone to see.  This is what my GitHub status page shows when I copied the same link that I showed you for my personal project:  https://imgur.com/PBUa3wz